# Make a dynamically following textview with counter

Tags: java, android, checkbox, textview, counter

So, i am making a stopwatch app right now. And now i need to make a text view that follow the tick of the stopwatch

The conditions are: stopwatch already exist, there are two textviews (one for second and one for minute) that will follow the numbers of the stopwatch that is counting and checkboxes that corresponds with the visibility of the textview. The textview is used as minute view and second view (literally) of the stopwatch
What should i do so that everytime the textview is shown, it will follow the digit of stopwatch as it goes on?

Comment: I'm still new to this and have tried to find a way to make a sync between them, but i can't find one. All i can get is just to take the text of the current time at the moment i click the checkbox, but not following the stopwatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use a `Timer` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). You can tell a `Timer` to `scheduleAtFixedRate` a `TimerTask` to run every time interval you decide.

In you case you want a `TimerTask` that runs every second (change this if you need more precision) so you can update your clock. From the `TimerTask` you should fire an event to your TextView telling it a new "second" is ready to be displayed.

You could send an event to the "seconds" TextView and then every 60 events have the "seconds" TextView notify the "minutes" TextView a "new" minute is ready for display. Or send the event to both TextViews.

Comment: Oh.. So by using this TimerTask, the TextView for showing the minute and second could be sync'ed for everytime the stopwatch change the second or minute, yes?

Comment: yes, you could start the `Timer` when you start your StopWatch (which is a kind of timer in the end) and use the `TimerTask` to notify the TextView it has to do a "plus one" operation. When you the stop your StopWatch then you also `cancel` the `Timer`.